# Incorrect window size with OCaml Graphics

Tags: graphics, ocaml, x11

**Description of the issue**

When using OCaml Graphics module, I often get a window with a wrong size ; and this isn't a predictable behaviour. The displayed window always has the required size, but for an unknown reason, OCaml sometimes considers that it has actually a different size, and this affects the drawing consequently.

Perhaps it is related to the window system ; I am using X11 (XQuartz) on OS X.

**Evidence of the issue**

Consider the following sequence :

```
open Graphics
let f () =
    Printf.printf "size_x = %d, size_y = %d\n" (size_x ()) (size_y ())
let () =
    open_graph "";
    resize_window 500 500;
    f ();
    Unix.sleepf 0.01
    f ();
    Unix.sleepf 0.1
    f ()
```

The expected result is a window of constant size 500x500, that is :

```
size_x = 500, size_y = 500
size_x = 500, size_y = 500
size_x = 500, size_y = 500
```

But I also get sometimes (with a strong probability)

```
size_x = 500, size_y = 500
size_x = 600, size_y = 450
size_x = 500, size_y = 500
```

or

```
size_x = 600, size_y = 450
size_x = 500, size_y = 500
size_x = 500, size_y = 500
```

or

```
size_x = 600, size_y = 450
size_x = 600, size_y = 450
size_x = 500, size_y = 500
```

In other words, this is a variable behaviour that seems to occur only a few tenths of a second after the opening of the window.

The result is the same whether I turn options `auto_synchronize` and `display_mode` true or false.

**Workaround**

I make sure all `resize_window` instructions are followed by `Unix.sleepf 0.1` at least (or by `synchronize (); Unix.sleepf 0.1` when `auto_synchronize` is turned off) ; of course, this isn't a very satisfactory solution…

Comment: Window resize is asynchronous under X11, the client tells the server to resize. But I would expect the client to return the new size even if the server hasn't finished resizing yet. Do you need the `sleep` after `synchronize`?

Comment: I use the `sleep` after `resize_window` to bypass the problem, giving the server the time to resize the window so that `size_x` and `size_y` return the new values, otherwise they return either the new or the old values (with strange behaviour as shown in the test). The best solution would be to have functions like `size_x` and `size_y` but giving the requested window size, not the actual.

Comment: The question was if you still need the sleep if you called synchronize. The reason why `size_x` and `size_y` can't give the requested window size is that the window may be resized by the window manager. The size can change even when the program didn't ask for it.

Comment: Whether I call `synchronize` or not, I need a `sleep` instruction after `resize_window` in order to have `size_x` and `size_y` giving the correct values. I should detail what I have said, because it wasn't very clear : the best solution would be to have functions like `size_x` and `size_y` giving the size the window system was requested for, i.e., if the window system just received an order to change window size (from the program or another external cause) to `x*y`, returning `x*y` even if the window system hasn't resized the window yet. But such functions doesn't seem to exist…